# Network jitter analyzer

Tags: unit-testing, testing, networking, integration-testing, rtp

I'm developing the application that sending MPEG video over IP network using RTP protocol.
In order to test it I'm looking for a software tool that can measure network jitter, recognize RTP packets reordering events and show results as a graph.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Wireshark: Open Main menu->telephony->RTP->Stream analysis...
More information is here: http://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP_statistics

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trace and then analyze it in [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Probably it won't recognize the RTP streams at first (it doesn't know the port number), but you can select one packet and choose 'Decode As.. RTP'. After that, go to 'Telephony / RTP / Stream Analysis' and you will get comprehensive RTP statistics.

Comment: In order to do it with Wireshark, I need to go through thousands RTP packets manually...

Answer (score 0):

@Dima, if you are looking for a software tool capable of measuring network jitter, I suggest you check out http://www.netrounds.com. This is a cloud-controlled software solution for IPTV MPEG transport monitoring in line with ETR 101 290. You can measure both PCR and RTP jitter.

RTP jitter will show any network jitter problems in your transport path, whereas PCR jitter will also include any jitter introduced by encoding/transcoding.

There is a free version of Netrounds available that supports monitoring of two IPTV MPEG transport streams (channels) concurrently. Channels are received by the probe/agent by IGMP join messages sent to the corresponding multicast groups.

DISCLAIMER: I am affiliated with Netrounds.